# Rotate border on nav

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project from PSD to HTML i am only stuck with this.

The people asking for the project wants me to make a top header with rotated lines. I tried using transform in the list items but nothing seems to work. I also tried to look it up but found nothing to the solution of my problem.
[This is how it has to be done.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnjDd.png)

I have my CSS like this:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 60px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
}
li {
    background-color: aqua;
    transform: rotate(-11deg);
    display: inline;
    padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Is it that maybe i should use it as an image instead trying to transform it myself?

Comment: I think you need skewX not rotate

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.content ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 60px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
}

.content li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 40px;
      height: 60px;
      line-height: 60px;
      position: relative;
      z-index:2;
      background-color:aqua;
      transform: skew(-20deg,0deg);
}

.content li a {
      display: inline-block;
      transform: skew(20deg,0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">menu</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

there is a [generator](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) you can use for visualization:

```css
.content ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display:flex;
}

.content li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 40px;
    line-height: 60px;
    z-index:2;
    background-color:aqua;
    clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
    -webkit-clip-path:polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">menu</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i used negative `margin-left:-30px` to glue them together
but im not sure if that is the best practice